# putting data in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hello so right now I'm learning SQL using php my admin. I am having a little trouble with INSERT INTO. I looked at the syntax of how to create an INSERT INTO, but I always get an error that I have the wrong version.Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong ?

```
   CREATE TABLE patient1(
patient_id INT (3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
place VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
profession VARCHAR (30)NOT NULL,
age INT (11),
PRIMARY KEY (patient_id)
)

INSERT INTO patient (patient_id, place, profession, age) VALUES (101, 'Indiana','Software', 23);
INSERT INTO patient (patient_id, place, profession, age) VALUES(102, 'Ohio', 'Teacher',45);
INSERT INTO patient (patient_id, place, profession, age) VALUES(103, 'Ohio', 'Doctor', 65);
INSERT INTO patient (patient_id, place, profession, age) VALUES(104, 'Indiana', 'Software', 34);
INSERT INTO patient (patient_id, place, profession, age) VALUES(105, 'Wisconsin', 'Pharmacist', 69);
```

Comment: Your table is named `patient1`, and you're inserting into `patient`? You also need a `;` after the create table statement. Furthermore, we need you to post the FULL error message for further help. "Always get an error that I have the wrong version." is not enough...

Comment: What error you have?

Answer (score 0):

Because `patient_id` have autoincrement you don't need include it on the statement.

```
INSERT INTO patient (place, profession, age) 
VALUES ('Indiana','Software', 23);
```

**EDIT:**

after double checking your code, the problem is you name the table `patient1` but insert into `patient`

Check **[demo](http://rextester.com/BWRPMU69775)** to see is working

Answer (score -1):

please check your table name correctly.that was the problem.

```
INSERT INTO patient1 (patient_id, place, profession, age) VALUES (101, 'Indiana','Software', 23);
INSERT INTO patient1 (patient_id, place, profession, age) VALUES(102, 'Ohio', 'Teacher',45);
INSERT INTO patient1 (patient_id, place, profession, age) VALUES(103, 'Ohio', 'Doctor', 65);
INSERT INTO patient1 (patient_id, place, profession, age) VALUES(104, 'Indiana', 'Software', 34);
INSERT INTO patient1 (patient_id, place, profession, age) VALUES(105, 'Wisconsin', 'Pharmacist', 69);
```